# Bootstrap popover stops after a few hovers in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, popover

I have a table with a dynamic number of rows. I would like to have a popover appear on hover over a certain element of each row. However, when I load the page, the popover works for the first few (3-6?) times, and then the popover disappears altogether.

```
       <div class="container">
              <table class="table" style="width:20%">
                    <tr ng-repeat="game in games.mlb">
                          <td>
                                {{ game.awayTeam }} <br> {{ game.homeTeam }}
                          </td>
                          <td>
                                {{ game.awayScore }} <br> {{ game.homeScore }}
                          </td>
                          <td>
                                <span data-toggle="popover" 
                                data-trigger="hover" 
                                data-content="Some content" 
                                style="float: right"> {{ game.status}} </span>
                          </td>
                    </tr>
              </table>
        </div>
```

This is the code for the table. As you can see, I'm trying to apply the popover on hover to a dynamic piece of text in the third column of each row of my table. When I load the page, this works for a while. Until it just... doesn't.

Here is the jquery:

```
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
              $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
        });
  </script>
```

Comment: Are table rows being loaded in after the `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();` call? Even though you're using `$(document).ready`, if rows are being loaded in after the call they won't have tooltips on them.

Comment: Also, note that you have a typo here: `<tr ng-repeat="game in games.mlb>`. You're missing a `"` at the end of the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-repeat` doesn't work well with `$(document).ready`, since there's no guarantee that the `$(document).ready` call will be before the entire `ng-repeat` is loaded.

This actually turns the question into more of an Angular question (which can be determined from your use of `ng-repeat`) from a Bootstrap question. Since there's no callback at the end of a `ng-repeat` loop, you could use directives instead.

This would be the HTML for your table row:

```
<tr ng-repeat="game in games.mlb" my-repeat-directive>
  <!-- things go here -->
</tr>
```

And this would be your associated Javascript:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('myRepeatDirective', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    // set your popovers per row element
  };
})
```

Comment: I've created a static table with no angular and fixed values, and it appears you're right as far as diagnosing the issue. The popover works with no angular in the equation.

Comment: Update. I ditched JQuery, and went full Angular instead. Instead of making my own directives, I used the popovers listed in Angular-UI Bootstrap (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). It now works great. You clue'd me in on the issue. Thanks!